# how to change label to textbox in gridview on checkbox click using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I got a gridview where checkboxes are displayed for each and every row. Upon clicking the checkbox the alternate names label should change to textbox with the content in it remaining as it is.

[image]

If the user unchecks the checkbox the textbox should again revert back to label.

How can I achieve this in Jquery.

The code behind code is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server" OnClick="checkboxing()" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City Name Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="NameId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name_Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="CityName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Geo Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="GeoName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("geoname") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ascii Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="AsciiName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("asciiname") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Alternate Names" SortExpression="AlternateNames">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="AlternateNames" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("alternateNames") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="AlternateNames" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("alternateNames") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Longitude">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Longitude" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("longitude") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Latitude">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Latitude" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("latitude") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

The Javascript that executes on checking/unchecking the checkbox is the following one:

```js
 function checkboxing() {
            alert("im here in checkboxing");
            $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    alert("This is so true ");
                }
                else {
                    alert("false");
                }
            });
        }
```

Now my intention is

1. To change the alternate names - Label to Textbox with contents in it remaining as it is for the user to edit,
2. If the user unchecks the checkbox later, the contents should revert with textbox again changing to Label.

How can achieve this using JQuery

Comment: The name should be `input` instead of `label`, use  `class` each row item instead of `id`. 
Suggestion : from `input:checked` find the `parent row` and find `name`
Please include the html generated, not ASP. I can help more

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to achieve it

1 dynamically create elements on each checkbox click 
2 create both label and textbox but hide them on the basis of checkbox event

since you are using strongly typed views the second one should be the better option

if you use the client side input elements you could have dynamically append the element on the basis of click function.

now i would recommend the 2nd method instead of the 1st one because the 2nd one will manipulate the dom which in your case is not a necessity where as the 2nd option will only add a hidden class to your element which is less complex and also a better in terms of performance

Comment: It mea ans you need both label and textbox in the view but when you click on checkbox just hide the label and show the textbox from frontend jquery or other client side scripting

Answer (score 0):

The name should be `input` instead of `label`, use `class` each row item instead of `id`.

Suggestion : from `input:checked` find the `parent row` and find `name`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g0uf22vf/)

Answer (score 0):

> - you can change the DOM from label to input field
> - Upon toggling the checkbox, you can enable/disable.
> - You can also set custom styles to the disabled input field like as if its a label.

Hope the idea is of any help

Answer (score 0):

Try Below. I am assuming you are trying to edit the last row and you have only one checkbox each row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("table input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function (event) {                
            var obj = $(event.target);
            var tr = $(obj).closest("tr");
            var td = $(tr).find("td:last");                
            if ($(obj).is(":checked")) {
                var data = $(td).find("span").html();
                $(td).html("<input id=none value=" + data + " />");

            }
            else {
                var data = $(td).find("input").val();
                $(td).html("<span >"+data+"</span>" );
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below codes

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleControl(chk)
    {
        var cell = $(chk).parent();
        var lbl = $(cell).siblings().find('#lblNames');
        var txtbx = $(cell).siblings().find('#txtNames');
        var str;

        if($(chk).is(':checked'))
        {
            str = $(lbl).text();
            $(lbl).hide();
            $(txtbx).val(str);
            $(txtbx).show();
        }
        else {
            $(lbl).show();
            $(txtbx).hide();
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server" OnClick="toggleControl(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>                   
            </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Alternate Names"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblNames"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text='Hello World!'>
               </asp:Label>
               <input type="text" id="txtNames" style="display:none;" />                   
            </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

```
Default.aspx.cs file codes:

    namespace aspnetWeb
    {
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Student> list = new List<Student>();

            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
            list.Add(new Student { ID = 1, Count = 20 });

            GridView1.DataSource = list.AsQueryable();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I executed and tested it